# "[Process completed]" Terminal self exiting

Tags: mac, terminal

My terminal is self exiting only showing this every time I open it and not letting me type anything in

Last login: Wed Jan  4 14:02:15 on console

[Process completed]

Any clues or anything? I can't change my .bashrc or .bash_profile b/c of this

Comment: You can change those, just not through the terminal. Try something like TextWrangler [link](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that something in .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .profile is executing `exit` or a similar command which ends the shell process.

Use the TextEdit app built into OS X to open these and examine. A [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/303516/open-hidden-configuration-files-without-using-terminal) shows how to see and open files beginning with a dot in the TextEdit open file window.

Comment: Yep, likely one of the profile files is exiting or taking an error.

Comment: You can suppress startup files by creating a terminal with **Shell > New Command**. Run the command `bash --noprofile`, for example. Then you can examine/edit the files using that terminal.