# Check if file is visible in OSX 10.10 with terminal

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Using commands within the terminal how can I check to see if a specific file is visible or hidden for a user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to hide files from OS X Finder (unless it's set up to show hidden files, or the user [wants to see these files in a file dialog](https://superuser.com/a/303551)):

- Rename so the name starts with a period (`.`), e.g. `.bash_profile`. This is common with software with Unix roots.
- Set the *hidden* file flag. Some system folders, notable `~/Library`, have this flag by default.

The former is easy to see by running `ls -A` (`-A` showing files whose names start with a period), for the latter you need to use `ls -lO` and look for the value `hidden` in the column between owning group name and file size.

Answer (score 1):

Simply…

`file.doc` is visible

`.file.doc` is hidden

The user can choose to view invisibles, so a hidden flag is not sufficient to make any file 'unobtainable' to the user, if they are resourceful enough.